# Can I define which field of a specific class is the one to watch in the debugger?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Creating a watch on a `TreeNode`, for example, displays an expandable watch item with the value column showing the `Text` property value.

**Can I define what property, or field/attribute is to be used for my own derived classes?** I cannot find any documentation on that one, yet it really would prepare things for comfortable debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [DebuggerDisplayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute.aspx).

For instance if you want the Visible property to be displayed as default you add

```
[DebuggerDisplay("Visible={Visible}")]
public class MyTreeNode
{ ....
```